# How to override firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, applet, browser-cache

I'm using Firefox to view my applets, but when I make changes it's still the old version that Firefox is displaying.  The only way I can change the version Firefox is showing me is by changing the names of the html AND the .class or jar files.  Ctrl Shift R isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />` in the `<head>` tag should cause Firefox (or any browser for that matter) to not cache anything at all on that particular page.

Comment: Hm, this does not seem to work for me on Ubuntu 11.04, openjdk-6, Firefox 13.0.1 :-(

Answer (score 2):

Test applets in the appletviewer whenever possible.  It does not cache classes.

For deployment, deploy them via JNLP whenever possible (user has Next Generation JRE) for more reliable class update.

Answer (score 1):

Try linking it with `myapplet.class?somerandomstring`. Then the Browser thinks "maybe its generated dynamically, so i need to reload it". At least with images it works very well.

Comment: Works nicely for <applet archive="my.jar?randomstring">

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+Del and then select cache checkbox with the interval you want to clear from the top of the window. Then click OK button.

Comment: Wait, would this delete all of my cache?  I don't wanna do it if it could.